# How to fix Notifications with Google Calendar

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm performing an integration with Google Calendar and I'm having a problem regarding Popup Notifications in Events.

I first create the Calendar through APIS, then create a CalendarList, then create a calendar access rule for a specific user, and finally create the Events.

What happens is that this user that I added through a rule does not receive the notifications I create in CalendarList and Event.

```cs
public void calendar()
{
    Calendar calendar = new Calendar();

    calendar.Summary = "Calendar Test";
    calendar.Description = "Calendar description";
    calendar.TimeZone = "America/Sao_Paulo";
    calendar.Location = "Name site";

    var result = service.Calendars.Insert(calendar).Execute();
}

public void calendarList(string calendarId)
{
    CalendarListEntry calendarList = new CalendarListEntry();

    calendarList.Id = calendarId;
    calendarList.Selected = true;
    calendarList.Primary = false;
    calendarList.ColorId = "11";

    calendarList.DefaultReminders = EventReminder();

    var result = service.CalendarList.Insert(calendarList).Execute();
}

public List<EventReminder> LembreteEvento()
{
    List<EventReminder> events = new List<EventReminder>();

    EventReminder reminder = new EventReminder();

    reminder.Method = "popup";
    reminder.Minutes = 5;
    events.Add(reminder);

    return events;
}

public void createRule()
{
    AclRule rule = new AclRule();
    ScopeData scope = new ScopeData();

    scope.Type = "user";
    scope.Value = "teste@gmail.com";

    rule.Role = "reader";
    rule.Scope = scope;

    var result = service.Acl.Insert(rule, idCalendario).Execute();
}

private void createEvent(string calendarId)
{
    Event event = new Event();

    event.Summary = "Name Event";
    event.Description = "Description Event";
    event.Location = "mysite";

    EventDateTime dateStart = new EventDateTime();
    dateStart.DateTime = "2019-04-09 10:00:00";

    EventDateTime dateEnd = new EventDateTime();
    dateEnd.DateTime = "2019-04-09 11:00:00";

    event.Start = dataInicio;
    event.End = dataFim;

    event.GuestsCanInviteOthers = false;
    event.GuestsCanModify = false;
    event.GuestsCanSeeOtherGuests = false;
    event.ColorId = "11";
    evento.Locked = true;
    event.PrivateCopy = true;
    event.Visibility = "public";
    event.Status = "confirmed";
    event.Transparency = "transparent";

    event.Creator = new Event.CreatorData()
    {
        DisplayName = "Name",
        Email = "teste@gmail.com"
    };

    event.Organizer = new Event.OrganizerData()
    {
        DisplayName = "Name",
        Email = "teste@gmail.com"
    };

    event.Source = new Event.SourceData()
    {
        Title = "Name",
        Url = "mysite"
    };

    event.Reminders = new Event.RemindersData()
    {
        UseDefault = true
    };

    var request = Service.Events.Insert(event, calendarId).Execute();
}
```

Comment: Try changing the order a bit.   create calendar -> add access rule -> add calendar list for access rule  user.

Comment: I already tried to change the order as I said, but it did not work either.